# How to Bring the custom values of product detail view to cart page in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am adding some of custom fields to product detail view. 
[image]

But the values which are not reflecting in cart page,[image]

My Question is how can i get those selected values? I am new to Magento. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using custom session variable. for this you have to rewrite/overwrite  `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php`
controller in this controller you will find a `addAction` place

```
$setter = 'setMyCustomCart'.$params['product'];
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->$setter($params);
```

this code before `if($params['isAjax'] == 1){`

and in `app\design\frontend\<YOUR_PACKAGE>\<YOUR_THEME>\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml` wherever you want your custom value you can use

```
<?php
      $getter = 'getMyCustomCart'.$_item->getProductId();
      $getMyCustomCart =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->$getter();
      echo $getMyCustomCart['testfield']; ?>
```

I have use **testfield** as a name of custom field replace this by name of your custom field.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: First of all I didn't get   if($params['isAjax'] == 1){   in  CartController.php file.

Comment: ok are you able to find `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();` if yes then put the code below this line. le me know if it is there or not.

Comment: Yes I found and I have added below that. And i am accessing the session values in app/design/frontend/{{theme}}/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml.  But i'm getting Black Cart page in UI. Please help me

Comment: add if isset condition to check if data is their then only it will access the field

Comment: Every time those downpayment field should populate into cart page

Comment: show your default value in else case and also if you are getting a proper value at `$getter` your $getter must have value which you have at time of setting i.e. `$setter` in controller echo both valriable to cross check.

Comment: Now values are coming in the cart page. But I want to append those values inside the cart. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: do you have another question for this @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117753/how-to-append-the-this-getitems-value-with-my-session-values

Comment: Yes Please help me.